# svn status does not show the deletion

Tags: svn

I encountered a very strange problem today, I did a svn merge from branch to trunk, and the output of merging as below, as we can see, the file 'sncpStateInd.cfg' was deleted by merging, but the svn status does not show it, can anybody help me to check it? Thanks

```
--- Merging r30994 through r31381 into 'aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg':

U     aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/testSuiteODU.cfg

A     aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/lib/telink_metric.cfg

A     aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/lib/telink_srlg.cfg

D   aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/lib/sncpStateInd.cfg


[xuzhijun@test aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/lib]$ svn st
 M      .
A  +    telink_metric.cfg
A  +    telink_srlg.cfg
[xuzhijun@test aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/ccp10_scripts/cfg/lib]$ svn pl- v
```